# Angular2 RouteGuards

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

i'm using Angular2's RouteGuards, so i have two classes 'OperatorAccess' and 'ExpertAccess' implementing CanActivate. If the user navigates to a specific url, access is checked and if the user hasn't the right access level, it is navigated to a login page (Login Page itself gets the target url via query params.) This works fine.
But: If the user BOOKMARKS the login page I need to know the access level of the target url in order to check against operator or expert.
I have no idea how to do this.
Has anyone done something similar before and can give me a hint ?

Comment: I think you can implement another class for Login route and get target url from query string to check if user has or not access.

Comment: Well, i already HAVE the target url. What I need is the target url's access level; it would be nice to get the target url's RouteGuard from router.

Comment: I don;t know how do you usually get it. Normally you should be able to call an api from RouteGuard and on subscribe you return true or false like on https://github.com/icehowler/ApiScanner/blob/master/ApiScanner.Web/ClientApp/app/components/account/auth.guard.ts